# set CSS rule of tag to match another tag

Tags: css

let's assume we have this rule:

```
.ruleA{
color: black;
}
```

how we set another rule that reads

```
.ruleB{
color: get the color value of ruleA;
}
```

is that possible without using jquery, i mean using css rules directly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: with just css you can't do it. but perhaps with some javascript (jquery library or something) you should be able to do so.

Comment: hi @Jan Hančič, jquery-ui have this nice themes, some times i don't want my components to have the same class, only inherit the font or to have the same background color, so that my component is blended smoothly with the design but without inheriting all the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with pure CSS. Look into [Less](http://www.lesscss.org) or [SASS](http://www.sass-lang.com) for that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. You can use `color:inherit` property if that 'div' is nested.